# Remove Headers from each page break using excel formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am loading a text file to Excel 2016.Below is the example for your reference

[image]

When I load the data to excel I see Headers in every page break as shown in the below image.

[image]

I don't need these lines and I have to delete them, hence tried writing formula. I have written multiple conditions to get the data I want. However since there are headers in each page break the data is not matching.

The headers always start with ------ and ends with ------ (It is 10 rows in excel as shown below.I tried writing the below condition to get start and end of the line of the headers, but not successful.

=IFERROR(FIND("-----------",E10,1),"")

---

TE Connectivity

ZSD4R708
 PR2 (028)--TE220664 --21.11.2017(18:50:45)

---

How can I get rid of these 10 lines in the entire data set. All I need is 0 in one of columns as shown below (every time header repeats). Could we combine Rows and Find function, I am not sure.. Any help in this greatly appreciated.

0   ---------------------------
0   TE Connectivity
0
0      ZSD4R708
0    PR2 (028)--TE220664 --21.11.2017(18:50:45)
0
0   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thanks,
Ganesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question properly, I got the below to work with crafty use of `MATCH` and `OFFSET` and `ROW`

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("TE Connectivity",OFFSET(B1:B7,MAX(2-ROW(),-5),0),0)),0,"")
```

[image]